# Eclipse count.fori code template / postfix completion similar to IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a feature called Postfix Completion. Is this available in Eclipse?

For example, in IntelliJ when you have

```
int count = 10;

count.fori
```

it becomes

```
int count = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

}
```

I use both IDEs but i prefer Eclipse for its views but IntelliJ has some interesting code completions and templates that make life easier.

Comment: There is a plug-in for that: https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion

Answer (score 2):

Yes, postfix completion [was introduced in Eclipse 4.14](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/jdt.php#postfix-completion) (December 2019).

It works similarly to IntelliJ. For your example, if you type

```
    int count = 10;
    count.
```

and invoke autocomplete ("content assist", Ctrl-Space), Eclipse will offer the completion "foriub", which will yield the same loop as in IntelliJ. There's also "forllb", which will yield a loop counting backwards.

Notes:

- For content assist to work, the cursor must be behind the dot. Also, the dot is required to invoke the postfix completion.
- Postfix completion must be enabled in the Eclipse preferences (should be enabled by default). To check, got to Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Content Assist / Advanced. There, the category "Java Postfix Template Proposals" must be enabled.

Comment: good to know that it is now standard. I am still using the plug in https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion because it works well enough

Answer (score 0):

Type `for` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.